# GNU Parallel: Run bash code that reads (seq number) from pipe?

Tags: bash, curl, gnu-parallel

I would like parallel to read the (seq numbers) pipe, so I would like running something like that:

`seq 2000 | parallel --max-args 0 --jobs 10 "{ read test; echo $test; }"`

Would be equivalent to running:

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
...
echo 2000
```

But unfortunately, the pipe was not read by parallel, meaning that it was instead ran like:

```
echo
echo
echo
...
echo
```

And the output is empty.

Does anyone know how to make parallel read (seq numbers) pipe? Thanks.

Comment: Aside: `parallel` is not part of bash; it's an entirely independent project written in perl. (Its author is also quite active here; amended tagging appropriately, and they're likely to show up)

Comment: Also, you probably need the `--pipe` argument to parallel, or its synonym `--spreadstdin`, to make content be on the children's stdin so `read` can access them. (The more usual thing is to use the argv instead of stdin; I'm unclear on why you don't want to do that here).

Comment: Quite the contrary, `parallel` *did* read from the pipe, *itself*, so there was nothing left for `read` to read. Also, with double quotes, `$test` is expanded before `parallel` ever runs, so even if `read` succeeds, you are executing `echo`, not `echo $test`, in each child process.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you please show me an example of using argv in parallel?

Comment: "Using argv in parallel" is how parallel _always_ works, by default, out-of-the-box; each instance's arguments go into `$1`, `$2`, etc. You have to do something (like use `-I {}`) to turn that off to get behavior that _isn't_ like that.

Comment: @user12345432109890, ...I've added an answer that should address your question in full.

Comment: I think you'd get an answer closer to what you are trying to do if you forgot about `parallel` for a moment and just showed the first 3-4 **actual commands** you really want to run. `echo` is a special case because a) it is a built-in and b) it is the default command for `parallel` which means the answers you get won't really help you much. As it is, the actual answer to your question is `seq 2000 | parallel` or maybe `seq 2000 | parallel echo`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `echo` is the default command for `xargs`. GNU Parallel will instead treat the input as a complete command line and run that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative with GNU `xargs` that does not require GNU `parallel`:

```
seq 2000 | xargs -P 10 -I {} "echo" "hello world {}"
```

Output:

```
hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 3
hello world 4
hello world 5
.
.
.
```

From `man xargs`:

> `-P max-procs`: Run up to `max-procs` processes at a time; the default is 1.  If max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time.

> `-I replace-str`: Replace occurrences of `replace-str` in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is spinning up a lot of copies of `/bin/echo`, not using bash's built-in `echo`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I agree with you there. I suspect that `echo` is just a placeholder in user12345432109890's code for a program to be called.

Comment: _nod_. The real question is whether there's room to reduce the number of separate invocations, as by passing more than one filename to each invocation of whatever the program they're starting really is.

Answer (score 1):

You want the input to be piped into the command you run, so use `--pipe`:

```
seq 2000 |
   parallel --pipe -N1 --jobs 10 'read test; echo $test;'
```

But if you really just need it for a variable, I would do one of these:

```
seq 2000 | parallel --jobs 10 echo
seq 2000 | parallel --jobs 10 echo {}
seq 2000 | parallel --jobs 10 'test={}; echo $test'
```

I will encourage you to spend 20 minutes on reading chapter 1+2 of https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014 Your command line will love you for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs` instead of parallel *while still using a shell* (instead of starting up a new copy of the `/bin/echo` executable per line to run) would look like:

```
seq 2000 | xargs -P 10 \
  sh -c 'for arg in "$@"; do echo "hello world $arg"; done' _
```

This is likely to be faster than the existing answer by Cyrus, because starting executables takes time; even though starting a new copy of `/bin/sh` takes longer than starting a copy of `/bin/echo`, because this isn't using `-I {}`, it's able to pass many arguments *to each copy of `/bin/sh`*, thus amortizing that time cost over more numbers; and that way we're able to used the copy of `echo` built into `sh`, instead of the separate `echo` executable.